# MongoDB databases within databases

Tags: mongodb, database

I'd like to use a database within a database, so I have the `dev DB` with my development data in it and my `test DB` with all my test data. However, it doesn't look possible to put DBs inside of DBs with Mongo. So I assume an alternate solution is to create a different Mongo connection altogether for dev and test. So I have a dev_data directory and a test_data directory, each with its own `mongod.lock` file and each listening on a different port. Is that a good solution? How do I do that?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Just use two different databases on the same MongoDB server.

Comment: so if I am running the dev and test DB on localhost, how do I configure them to use different ports? and also, when I run the mongo or mongod commands, how to do I configure the commands to talk with the right DB?

Comment: Why would you want them on different ports? Whatever driver you're using will have some way to select the database you're using over the connection.

Comment: I guess I'd rather have them running on different ports. I don't know how to do that. Also, I know how to tell >mongod where to look for each database, but I don't know how to tell >mongo where to look.

Comment: different ports to prevent me from confusing test and dev?

Comment: Umm "myappdb-prod" and "myappdb-dev" as the name. Which is what "Just use two databases means". I think you'll find that some things like meteor for example are set up with naming like that by default.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily possible. You can start as many mongod processes as you want like this — just make sure the data directories exist and both data folder plus log file are writeable:

```
mongod --dbpath /opt/dev --port 27001 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/dev.log
mongod --dbpath /opt/prd --port 27002 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/prd.log
```

If this is really necessary or if multiple databases would be sufficient is another matter, but you'll know best what you require for your situation.

Comment: cool thanks, different log files too, good to know. there must be pros/cons to using different ports. I assume different ports could mean test/dev are running at the same time. I could see this being both a good and bad thing.

Comment: upvoted, will accept the answer once I verify this makes sense (to me)